On assumptions of local projection method
It is well known that Jorda(2005) proposed the following model called local projection:
$$y_{t+h} - y_{t-1} = \beta_h shock_{t} + \gamma_h ctr_{t-1} + \epsilon_{t,h}, h = 0,1,2,\dots,H.$$
I am trying to calculate AIC for such a model. To do this, I have to calculate the likelihood function, which in turn relies on the joint distribution of $\vec{\epsilon_t} = (\epsilon_{t,0},\epsilon_{t,1},\dots,\epsilon_{t,H})$. I guess that $\vec{\epsilon_t}$ has some $H+1$-dimensional Gaussian distribution since we usually estimate this model by OLS. But I have no idea how to determine the variance-covariance matrix of the distribution.
It seems reasonable for me to calculate $Var(\epsilon_{t,h})$ by Newey-West correction (Newey, West, 1987, 1994), though I am still not very sure about that.
What bothers me most is whether it is appropiote to assume $Cov(\epsilon_{t,h}, \epsilon_{t, j}) = 0$, since there may be autocorrelations between the residuals given the time-series context. I also do not know how to calculate these possibly-existing covariances. Can anyone please help me?
Note: I know there is a R-package with which one can estimate an LP and calculate the AIC. But I prefer to realise it by myself.

Cross-posted on Economics SE here.
